# How to do not show the parent activity after exit the Theme.Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-activity

I want to create an simple activity which displays a dialog.
I have in the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog
```

and in the onCreate() method of the activity:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout), false);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setView(layout);

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

When I launch the app, it displays properly the dialog, however when I press back button key, it shows me the parent activity as in the image

[image]

What I want to achieve is only show the dialog and when the user exits the dialog, the app exits. I do not want to see this nosense pop-up in the middle after that. 
How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want to achieve is only show the dialog and when the user exits the dialog, the app exits. I do not want to see this nosense pop-up in the middle after that. How can I do that?

For this you can set a `OnDismissListener()` on your `AlertDialog` and in it call `finish()` to close the `Activity` inside of `onDismiss()`. You just set

[Dialog Interface OnDismiss](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html)

However, what you are doing in your `manifest.xml` is setting the `Activity` itself as having a `Dialog theme`. This means you shouldn't need the `AlertDialog`. You can just set `R.layout.activity_dialog.xml` in `setContentView()` of your `Activity` in `onCreate()` and it should give you the same type of effect without the need of the `AlertDialog` then you can call `finish()` in `onBackPressed()` of your `Activity` and wherever else you need to.

Comment: You are absolutely right!! It makes no sense inflate the layout in the activity and setup the Theme.Dialog in the manifest xD. Thanks dude